# Verification of submodules initialization [Git]

Tags: git, git-submodules

Recently I started using git submodules in my project.
One of my scripts creates a repo with submodules. I would like to create a function which checks if the submodules were initialized successfully.

What are good indications to verify?

I guess, we first should check if there is a `.git` directory in the main repo. Then I should check each submodule, but for what?

Hope my question is understandable, if not, I would glad to specify more.

Answer (score 3):

The `git submodule status` command outputs a parseable line for each submodule:

```
status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
    Show the status of the submodules. This will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each
    submodule, along with the submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1. Each SHA-1 will
    possibly be prefixed with - if the submodule is not initialized, + if the currently checked out submodule
    commit does not match the SHA-1 found in the index of the containing repository and U if the submodule has
    merge conflicts.
```

If you just want to know that each submodule is initialized, it would suffice to do:

```bash
if git submodule status | grep --quiet '^-'; then
    echo "A git submodule is not initialized."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do e.g.

`git submodule foreach status` and `git submodule summary`

and double check the .gitmodules file in the parent repository.

Answer (score 0):

To better parse git submodule summary, use Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019): The "`git submodule summary`" subcommand showed shortened commit object names by mechanically truncating them at 7-hexdigit, which has been improved to let "`rev-parse --short`" scale the length of
the abbreviation with the size of the repository.

See [commit 0586a43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0586a438f64bc13d6634379cbeeaa96c9e8241d9) (03 Feb 2019) by [Sven van Haastregt (`svenvh`)](https://github.com/svenvh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 257507a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/257507a35e1d13d8849bbdf9324a060232a82bdf), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `git-submodule.sh`: shorten submodule SHA-1s using rev-parse

> Until now, `git submodule summary` was always emitting 7-character SHA-1s that have a higher chance of being ambiguous for larger repositories.
> Use `git rev-parse --short` instead, which will determine suitable short SHA-1 lengths.

> When a submodule hasn't been initialized with "`submodule init`" or not cloned, `git rev-parse` would not work in it yet; as a fallback, use the original method of cutting at 7 hexdigits.

---

Note that With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), `git submodule summary` from "[`git submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bbdba3d88320cd99ae3425f31e4c20213a877cac/Documentation/git-submodule.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule))</sup> is getting rewritten in C.

It is no longer part of `git-submodule.sh`.

See [commit e83e333](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83e3333b5770815e9c2e3aee48c305257385bbb) (13 Aug 2020) by [Prathamesh Chavan (`pratham-pc`)](https://github.com/pratham-pc).
See [commit ede8a5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ede8a5bb6b16af70542bc9d02d17371e83764837), [commit 180b154](https://github.com/git/git/commit/180b154b0900766cf69f79d19432cd04bbcc8a91), [commit 6414c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6414c3d3166152657ea55b7944303a308b0b2d59) (13 Aug 2020) by [Shourya Shukla (`periperidip`)](https://github.com/periperidip).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bbdba3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbdba3d88320cd99ae3425f31e4c20213a877cac), 09 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83e3333b5770815e9c2e3aee48c305257385bbb): port submodule subcommand 'summary' from shell to C
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Stefan Beller</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Kaartic Sivaraam</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Prathamesh Chavan</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Shourya Shukla</sup>

> Convert submodule subcommand 'summary' to a builtin and call it via 'git-submodule.sh'.
>
> The shell version had to call `$diff_cmd` twice, once to find the modified modules cared by the user and then again, with that list of modules to do various operations for computing the summary of those modules.
>
> On the other hand, the C version does not need a second call to `$diff_cmd` since it reuses the module list from the first call to do the aforementioned tasks.
>
> In the C version, we use the combination of setting a child process' working directory to the submodule path and then calling '`prepare_submodule_repo_env()`' which also sets the '`GIT_DIR`' to '`.git`', so that we can be certain that those spawned processes will not access the superproject's ODB by mistake.
>
> A behavioural difference between the C and the shell version is that the shell version outputs two line feeds after the '[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e83e3333b5770815e9c2e3aee48c305257385bbb/Documentation/git-log.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup>' output when run outside of the tests while the C version outputs one line feed in any case.
> The reason for this is that the shell version calls log with '`--pretty=format:<fmt>`' whose output is followed by two echo calls; '`format`' does not have "terminator" semantics like its '`tformat`' counterpart.
> So, the log output is terminated by a newline only when invoked by the user and not when invoked from the scripts.
>
> This results in the one & two line feed differences in the shell version.
>
> On the other hand, the C version calls log with '`--pretty=<fmt>`' which is equivalent to '`--pretty:tformat:<fmt>`' which is then followed by a '`printf("\n")`'.
> Due to its "terminator" semantics the log output is always terminated by newline and hence one line feed in any case.
>
> Also, when we try to pass an option-like argument after a non-option argument, for instance:
>
> ```
> git submodule summary HEAD --foo-bar  
>
> (or)  
>
> git submodule summary HEAD --cached
> ```
>
> That argument would be treated like a path to the submodule for which the user is requesting a summary.
> So, the option ends up having no effect.
> Though, passing '`--quiet`' is an exception to this:
>
> ```
> git submodule summary HEAD --quiet
> ```
>
> While 'summary' doesn't support '`--quiet`', we don't get an output for the above command as '`--quiet`' is treated as a path which means we get an output only if a submodule whose path is '`--quiet`' exists.
>
> The error message in case of computing a summary for non-existent submodules in the C version is different from that of the shell version.